# Как присвоить класс родительской рубрике

Tags: php, wordpress

Здравствуйте. Нашел в интернете функцию:

```
function my_categories() {

  $current_category = get_query_var('cat');
  $categories=  get_categories();
  $a = "\n";
  $html = '';
  if(!empty($categories)){
    $html .= '<ul>'.$a;
      foreach ($categories as $cat) {
        $class = ($current_category == $cat->cat_ID) ? ' current-cat': '';
        if ($cat->category_parent == 0){
          $html .= '<li class="cat-item HEADING' . $class . '">';
          $html .= '<a href="' . get_category_link($cat->cat_ID) . '" ';
          $html .= 'title="View all posts filed under ';
          $html .=  $cat->cat_name .'">' . $cat->cat_name. '</a>'.$a;
          $childcats= get_categories('child_of='.$cat->cat_ID);
          if(!empty($childcats)){
          $html .= '<ul class="children">'.$a;
            foreach ($childcats as $ccat) {
              $class = ($current_category == $ccat->cat_ID) ? ' current-cat': '';
              $html .= '<li class="cat-item' . $class . '">';
              $html .= '<a href="' . get_category_link($ccat->cat_ID) . '" ';
              $html .= 'title ="View all posts filed under ';
              $html .=  $ccat->cat_name .'">' . $ccat->cat_name. '</a></li>'.$a;
            }
            $html .= '</ul>'.$a;
          }
          $html .= '</li>'.$a;
        }
      }
      $html .= '</ul>'.$a;
      return $html;
    }
  }
```

Она присваивает класс (HEADING) родительским рубрикам:

```
<ul class="categorymenu">

<li class="HEADING cat-item cat-item-10"><a>cat1</a>
     <ul class='children'>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-13"><a>subcat1</a> </li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-11"><a>subcat2</a> </li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="HEADING cat-item cat-item-14"><a>cat2</a>
     <ul class='children'> ......
```

Возможно ли подправить данную функцию так, чтобы она добавляла класс только в те рубрики, которые имеют дочерние рубрики?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function my_categories() {

  $current_category = get_query_var('cat');
  $categories=  get_categories();
  $a = "\n";
  $html = '';
  if(!empty($categories)){
    $html .= '<ul>'.$a;
      foreach ($categories as $cat) {
        $class = ($current_category == $cat->cat_ID) ? ' current-cat': '';
        if ($cat->category_parent == 0){
          $childcats= get_categories('child_of='.$cat->cat_ID);
          if(!empty($childcats)){
              $html .= '<li class="cat-item HEADING' . $class . '">';
          } else {
              $html .= '<li class="cat-item' . $class . '">';
          }
          $html .= '<a href="' . get_category_link($cat->cat_ID) . '" ';
          $html .= 'title="View all posts filed under ';
          $html .=  $cat->cat_name .'">' . $cat->cat_name. '</a>'.$a;
          if(!empty($childcats)){
          $html .= '<ul class="children">'.$a;
            foreach ($childcats as $ccat) {
              $class = ($current_category == $ccat->cat_ID) ? ' current-cat': '';
              $html .= '<li class="cat-item' . $class . '">';
              $html .= '<a href="' . get_category_link($ccat->cat_ID) . '" ';
              $html .= 'title ="View all posts filed under ';
              $html .=  $ccat->cat_name .'">' . $ccat->cat_name. '</a></li>'.$a;
            }
            $html .= '</ul>'.$a;
          }
          $html .= '</li>'.$a;
        }
      }
      $html .= '</ul>'.$a;
      return $html;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Спасибо, Fike. Работает.

Comment: @Дмитрий80, да в общем-то даже не за что, я всего лишь перетасовал пару строчек за пятнадцать секунд.